# Change window height dynamically

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Good day,

I'm trying to dynamically resize my panel which is inside my window, but it doesn't work. Does it come from my layout config?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ar2

Also, do you think it's a good approach to use only one panel which is updated for each tab or is it better to create a different panel for each tab?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set a listener for activating a tab and place a callback function on it to resize the specific panel.